# MVC Post method not taking any information from get method??

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

I have an extremely confusing case. I currently have the following code

```
//get method
public ActionResult EmailValidation(string email, string token)
    {
        EmailValidationViewModel model = new EmailValidationViewModel();
        model.email = email;
        model.token = token;
        Member existingMember = workflow.GetMemberByEmail(model.email, vendor.VendorID);

        if(existingMember != null)
        {
          return View();
        }
    }


     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmailValidation(EmailValidationViewModel model)
    {
    }
```

Now the above code, which I have already tested on a different page, loads the information in the model to the post method automatically. I believe there is a problem with the new view with the code I posted below that is inhibiting it from taking the information from the get method and sending it to the post method.

I believe it has something to do with the following code?

```
 [[Form_Start]]
<form action="/Mobile/Home/EmailValidation" id="EmailValidation" method="post" data-transition="slideup">
```

[[/Form_Start]]

if you guys might know why it returns the view with the data from the get method in one controller, but it doesnt in the next, please let me know. In addition if you require more information, also just tell me and I'll try to provide you with as much code as possible. Thanks !

Comment: Whaat do you want to do ? Both of your controller methods have parameters. Please explain in detail?

Comment: I require the email from my get method, to be passed to my post method. I have the exact same code but with a different view which works as needed, but for some reason in the ucrrent view it does not accept the email.

Comment: Please provide the entire contents of your form, including all controls.

Comment: I've solved the issue using a quickfix, where I just take in the parameters using a html hiddenfor. thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
    if(existingMember != null)
    {
      return View();
    }
```

is returning a View with no Model.

Change it to this:

```
    if(existingMember != null)
    {
      return View(existingMember);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wont work for me when I call my post method I need the model.

Comment: Your View has to include the model properties in the form to get data back to the server.  The ModelBinder will take care of it.